# Dividing variables in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

so I need to divide on variable by a number.
How can I do this?
I know about the C functions of DIV and MOD, but do not know how to use them in objective-C/cocoa-touch.
Heres an example of my code.

```
// hide the previous view
scrollView.hidden = YES;

//add the new view
scrollViewTwo.hidden = NO;

NSUInteger across;
int i;
NSUInteger *arrayCount;
// I need to take arrayCount divided by three and get the remainder
```

When I try to use / or % I get the error
"Invalid operands to binary expression ('NSUInteger and int)
Thanks for any help

Comment: Xcode is an IDE not a language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, should `arrayCount` really be a pointer?

Anyway, if `arrayCount` *should* be a pointer, you just need to dereference it...

```
NSInteger arrayCountValue = *arrayCount;
```

... and use the operators `/` (for division) and `%` (for getting the module):

```
NSInteger quotient = arrayCountValue / 3;
NSInteger rest = arrayCountValue % 3;
```

You can do it without the auxiliary variable too:

```
NSInteger quotient = *arrayCount / 3;
NSInteger rest = *arrayCount % 3;
```

And just remove the dereference operator `*` if `arrayCount` is not a pointer:

```
NSInteger quotient = arrayCount / 3;
NSInteger rest = arrayCount % 3;
```